# How do I determine the temperature of a fluid that was x degrees mixed with another fluid of y degrees?

Tags: temperature

Let's say that I have two, different fluids that are miscible and are of two different temperatures. How can I calculate the temperature of a mixture of the two fluids? Without a thermometer, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to have the **Mass**, **Heat capacity** and the **Temperature** of each fluid. then you can calculate the final temperature.

$Q = M.C.Delta(T)$

where $M$ is the mass, $C$ is heat capacity and $Delta(T)$ is the amount of changes in the temperature. first calculate how much energy do they take to get to the 0 temperature. let me show you in an example:

Imagine I have **2 kilograms** of ***fluid 1*** with heat capacity of **1.5** and with **25 degrees in Celsius**. and **5 kilograms** of ***fluid 2*** with capacity of **0.5** and temperature of **40 degrees**. I imagine they get to the 0 degrees of Celsius and then calculate how much energy they produce.

$Q1 = 2*1.5*25 = 75 J$

$Q2 = 5*0.5*40 = 100 J$

So I have total amount of **175 joules** and two fluids. now this heat (energy) is divided to these two fluids. where first fluid gets E1 and the second one gets E2 amount of Energy. and I know that:

$E1+E2 = 175 J   (1)$

Now If I use my main equation to determine the temperature that they rise to, I can get an answer. remember that both fluids get to a certain temperature that I call FT (Final Temperature) :

$E1 = 2*1.5*FT = 3*FT$

$E2 = 5*0.5*FT = 2.5*FT$

If I sum the two equation and use my  equation (1), I can calculate the final temperature. see:

$E1 + E2 = 3*FT + 2.5*FT$

$175 = FT (3 + 2.5) = 5.5 * FT$

**So :**  $FT = 175/5.5 = 31.81$ *Degrees of Celsius*

So that final temperature of the two fluids is about **31.81** . you can use other method too, but I used this method (turning them to 0 degrees of Celsius) to remove the delta from the formula.